# slack integration: 404 Expired url https://hooks.slack.com/commands

Tags: go, slack

Here is my golang app listening requests from slack command:
`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type SlackCmdResponse struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        if err := req.ParseForm(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        responseUrl := req.PostFormValue("response_url")
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            postBack(responseUrl)
        }()
        rj, err := json.Marshal(SlackCmdResponse{Text: "Test started"})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write(rj)

    })
    fmt.Println("listening 8383")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8383", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func postBack(responseUrl string) {
    fmt.Println("responseUrl", responseUrl)
    cResp := SlackCmdResponse{
        Text: "Test finished",
    }
    cj, err := json.Marshal(cResp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", responseUrl, bytes.NewReader(cj))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if resp != nil {
        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
        if b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(string(b))
        }
        if resp.Body != nil {
            resp.Body.Close()
        }
    }
}
```

I run it:

```
$ go run main.go
listening 8383
```

I use ngrok to make it accessible from the internet:

```
ngrok http 8383
```

I created slack slash command `/my-command` with `POST` option and pasted https URL that ngrok gave:

[image: slash command options - slack]

Now when I run `/my-command` in slack, I get slack reply `Test started`. And then in a second slack prints `Test finished`

For now, it's all fine.

## Problem

If I replace line

```
time.Sleep(time.Second)
```

by line

```
time.Sleep(time.Hour) // long test
```

I don't get slack printed "Test finished" in hour. Instead, I see in my app logs:

```
responseUrl https://hooks.slack.com/commands/T3GBFUZ64/86817661808/XRmDO21jYaP1Wzu7GFpNw9eW
404
Expired url
```

Looks like slack's response URL has an expiration time. How to **extend** this **expiration time**?

Or in a case of expiration, is there another way to send a message to the user about having the test finished? I have name and id of a user launching `/my-command`

```
req.PostFormValue("user_name")
req.PostFormValue("user_id")
```

So I want to run integration tests by slack which are longer than 2 hours and get a response after finishing such tests in slack.

Comment: I don't know anything about this(coz i'm beginner for the programming),but i like to learn things like this,can you say what is this and hope this link will be helped to you,if not sorry for me :(

https://gist.github.com/jmervine/8321794

Good luck  @Maxim :)

Answer (score 4):

> You can not increase the expire time for the URL that is a Slack internal setting.

## Using the Slack Web API

You can send unattended messages to any user through the [Slack Web API](https://api.slack.com/methods) which you need a token for it.

For more information check: https://api.slack.com/web.

### chat.postMessage

The Slack API has a `postMessage` command that allows the user to post messages to a channel, to the `slackbot` channel and to the user through `IM` channel (direct message). It seems you want to do the later which is quite simple.

### Post to an IM channel

[chat.postMessage#channels](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#channels)

Method Url: https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage

Posting to an IM channel is a little more complex when settings the value of `channel` depending on the value of `as_user`.

- If `as_user` is false:

  - Pass a username (`@chris`) as the value of `channel` to post to that user's @slackbot channel as the bot.
  - Pass the IM channel's ID (`D023BB3L2`) as the value of `channel` to post to that IM channel as the bot. The IM channel's ID can be retrieved through the [im.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.list) API method.
- If `as_user` is true:

  - Pass the IM channel's ID (`D023BB3L2`) as the value of `channel` to post to that IM channel as the authenticated user. The IM channel's ID can be retrieved through the im.list API method.
    To send a direct message to the user owning the token used in the request, provide the channel field with the a conversation/IM ID value found in a method like [im.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.list).

To send a direct message to the user ***owning*** the token used in the request, provide the `channel` field with the a conversation/IM ID value found in a method like [im.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.list).

### im.list

This method will return a list of direct messages channels if you don't have a channel open with the user yet you can call the `im.open`.

### im.open

This method is used to `open` a direct message `channel` with a specified user.

Documentation about `im.open` can be found [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.open).

### Example URL

`https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=**TOKEN**&channel=**Direct Channel ID**&text=HelloWorld&as_user=true&pretty=1`

Just replace `**TOKEN**` and `**Direct Channel ID**` with your values and it should send a direct message to the specified user.